# C language: Why doesn't my code create my requested directory

Tags: c, directory

The code is here below. I have around 1700 names in the txt file and they print into the terminal just fine. I just cant figure out why I dont produce any folders

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("names2.txt", "r");

    char buffer[256];

    while (fgets(buffer, 256, fp))
    {
        printf("%s", buffer);
        char *NewDir=buffer;
        printf("\ndetected string is: %s\n", NewDir);
        CreateDirectory(NewDir,NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` say about it?

Comment: Btw, `fgets` leaves the newline in `buffer`. You may want to remove that first

Comment: how do I remove it?

Comment: `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;`